Handle exception thrown from static block
I was confused by a program exiting silently without entering main, which turned out to be because a System.loadLibrary call in a static block threw UnsatisfiedLinkError. To narrow the problem down, this is a construct that makes the program fail silently:
public class T {
    static void bad() {
        throw new RuntimeException("Terror error!");
    }

    static {
        System.out.println("in static");
        bad();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("in main");
    }
}

When this is run, the process exits silently after printing only “in static”, with exit code 1. At least that is what happens with my current Java environment, “OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Homebrew (build 22.0.2, mixed mode, sharing)”.
Of course this can be fixed with a try-catch block around the bad call, but what if there isn’t such a block because it was unclear to the programmer it was needed? (Someone could have done this sort of thing in a library outside of my control, for instance.) Is there any way to hook in to handle an Error or RuntimeException thrown from a static block, to at least get a message that shows where the problem occurred?

not a problem with OpenJDK 23 - it prints the exception (but reproducible with OpenJDK 22 -- but not sure how that is a problem with "in a library outside of my control": once in main, the exception will be printed, unless the library class is loaded in the main static initializer)

Seems like a bug in that version. Try with older versions too.

@aled - good point, not reproducible with OpenJDK 21 (neither 17)

Its a JDK22 bug JDK-8329581. Avoid JDK22 if you can. It means that nothing is printed by failed main() if there are certain exceptions in initialisers such as UnsatisfiedLinkError or unresolved classes

@user85421 In my original scenario, the static block was in a superclass of the class that contained the main, so that’s at least one way it could happen: the main class extending someone else’s base class.

Okay, so it’s a JVM bug in a specific version. I’ll stop worrying about it.

As noted in comments, this is simply a bug in JDK22. Thanks!
